# Versions of lapply() and mclapply() that avoid redundant processing

Tags: r, lapply, mclapply

I am looking for versions of `lapply()` and `mclapply()` that only process unique elements of the argument list `X`. Does something like this already exist?

**EDIT**: In other words, I want `lapply()` to not bother processing duplicates, but I want `length(lapply(X, ...))` to equal `length(X)`, not `length(unique(X))` (and the appropriate values to match). Also, I am assuming each element of `X` is rather small, so taking unique values should not be too much trouble.

Current behavior:

```
long_computation <- function(task){
  cat(task, "\n")
# Sys.sleep(1000) # 
  return(task)
}
tasks <- rep(LETTERS[1:2], 2)
lapply(tasks, long_computation)

## A
## B
## A
## B
## [[1]]
## [1] "A"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "B"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "A"
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] "B"
```

Desired behavior:

lapply(tasks, long_computation)

```
## A
## B
## [[1]]
## [1] "A"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "B"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "A"
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] "B"
```

You can [find the intended use case here](https://github.com/wlandau-lilly/drake/issues/121#issuecomment-340652997).

Comment: unique the input combos before passing into the apply iterations

Comment: I would like to, but I need the full expanded results returned back to me, duplicates and all. Even if duplication is irregularly arranged, e.g `X = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 5, 7, 7, 7)`

Comment: In other words, The `length(lapply(X, ...))` should equal `length(X)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually seems to work:

```
lightly_parallelize_atomic <- function(X, FUN, jobs = 1, ...){
  keys <- unique(X)
  index <- match(X, keys)
  values <- mclapply(X = keys, FUN = FUN, mc.cores = jobs, ...)
  values[index]
}
```

And in my case, it's okay that `X` is atomic.

But it would be neat to find something already built into either a package or R natively.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this: I have created a `map` object which stores the result after `long_computation` for each unique 'key'. Once an existing 'key' is encountered, it returns from `map` else it calls the `long_computation` function and stores the result in `map` for future use. Not sure if it's the ideal way but it works.

```
tasks <- rep(letters[1:2], 2)
map=list()

lapply(tasks,function(t){if(t %in% names(.GlobalEnv$map)){
    return(.GlobalEnv$map[[t]])
}else{
    result=toupper(t)
        if(!t %in% names(.GlobalEnv$map)){
            .GlobalEnv$map[[t]]=result
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: It's a good thought, but it seems like there might be race conditions in `mclapply()` if multiple processes are trying to access `.GlobalEnv$map[[t]]`.

Comment: @landau But I have not used `mclapply` here. Also, if you want to go the parallel/multi-core route, variables can be shared between multiple cores, through `export` option. Might not be possible with `mclapply` but it is possible using `foreach`.